# Matlab: linkaxes squeezes my graph

Tags: matlab

I have drown several graphs thanks to "subplot" function on MatLab and it works well.
Nevertheless, I want all my graphs to have the same Y-scale so that I can compare them.
I used the "linkaxes" function and my all my graphs have the same scale but the problem is that some of my figures are "beheaded", lacking their upper part, or one of my figures is completely squeezed.
I don't get what happened. Could you please help me to solve the problem or tell me about another function that would be more appropriate in my case?

Here's part of my code:

```
for i=1:1:9
   m=n(i);
   fichier=sprintf('%d.txt',m);
   M=load(fichier);
   z=length(M(:,1));
   x=M(1:z,1);
   y=M(1:z,2);
   a(i)=subplot(2,4,i)
   contour3=plot(x,y)
   linkaxes(a,'y')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`linkaxes` creates a permanent link between the scales of several axes, so that you can subsequently perform zoom operations (perhaps interactively) on one, and have the other automatically update.

If you need that functionality, then `linkaxes` is the right command (although you could possibly also look at `linkprops`).

However if all you need is to ensure that the y-axis limits of your axes are the same, it will probably be easier (and you will have more control) if you set them directly. You can retrieve the y-axis limits using `ylim(axis_handle)` and set them using `ylim(axis_handle, [lower, upper])`, or alternatively with `get(axis_handle,'YLim')` and `set(axis_handle,'YLim',[lower,upper])`. You might also look at the `YLimMode` property of the axis, which determines whether the axis limits are directly set or automatically resized.

Comment: If the answer works for you, please mark it as accepted to make it easier for other users to find it.